# React can't set state after axios request

Tags: reactjs, axios, state

For some reason this sends an error when I try to store axios response in state with `setItem(response.data)` : `Objects are not valid as react child....If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`
Here's my code.

```
import Axios from 'axios'

function Menu() {
    const[items,setItems]=useState([])

    useEffect(async()=>{
        await Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/read').then((response)=>{
        console.log('DATA IS',response.data)
        setItems(response.data)
        console.log('items>>>>,',items)
        })      
      },[])
```

Comment: Can you also show what you are returning in the JSX?

Comment: return (
      
        <div className='Menu'>
            {items.length>0?<h1>{items}</h1>:<h1>nothing to display</h1>}
            <h1>Menu</h1>
            <button onClick={()=>setGameState('Quiz')}>Start</button>
        </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes time to set the state using hooks as it is asynchronous function. Try using this in your code

```
import Axios from 'axios'

function Menu() {
    const[items,setItems]=useState([])

    useEffect(async()=>{
        await Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/read').then((response)=>{
        console.log('DATA IS',response.data)
        setItems(response.data)
        console.log('items>>>>,',items)
        })      
      },[])

    useEffect(()=>{
       console.log(items);
},[items]);

        return (
      //some JSX
         )
}
```

Comment: Does that answer your entire question?

Comment: Yes, Is there a button for me to press here. I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: If you feel my answer is relevant you can upvote my answer just by hitting the upward arrow on the left side of answer. Arrow looks something like this ( ^ ) and mark it as correct answer by hitting checkmark (✓) below it, thank you.

Comment: Ok I did that . But my reputation might be too low to register that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This error means you are trying to render an object in jsx directly, in your case it's the `<h1>{items}</h1>`, you should iterate to render it

Comment: as long as ` items[0].url` is primitive it's ok

Comment: Thanks that worked well. The only thing is I want to just render one item in the items. 
   But it says the URL is undefined                                                                                           
 <div className='Menu'>
            {items.map(item=>(
                <h1>item1:{item[1].url}</h1>
            ))}

Comment: Ok that worked when I used ternary operator to make sure there was something in Items. Thanks everyone .

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at your jsx, I would suggest that you iterate through your items and show them on the ui

```
{items.map(c =>{
    return <h1>{c}</h1>
})}
```

Comment: Thank you. But Is there not a way for me to do them one at a time. And move on to the next item when a user presses a button? Its part of a quiz app.